# In angular micro front end architecture can the main application and micro front ends be of different angular versions?

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular-library, micro-frontend, angular-migration

Question:  In a micro front end architecture can the main applications remain in their own angular versions and consume micro front end apps from higher or lower angular versions?

Scenario:

I have a few angular applications that use various angular versions ( few are in v10, v11, v14 etc). And I have an angular shared library in v14, which is an implementation of a common feature required by all these applications. For using this library in these angular applications we have to migrate the lower version applications to v14. But these applications are developed and managed by independent teams, and due to various reasons immediate migrations are not possible. At the same we need a way to integrate this common feature to all these applications asap.

I am not familiar with micro front architecture. But just curios to know if moving to micro front end architecture will help in resolving this version related problem.

Is there any other approach that can solve this issue or is the migration of main applications the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Module Federation is a best tool to create micro frontends
[You can get solution here](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-your-4-steps-guide/)